# Ошибки TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable и ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python

Есть переменная train типа лист, которая содержит 2 элемента - массив картинок и массив меток. Я пытался в переменную **X** записать массив картинок и обработать с помощью reshape. 
Пробовал 2 способа, в обоих случаях ошибка.

Список с данными

```
 training_data.append([np.array(img), np.array(label)]) 
   ... 
 train = train_data[:-500]
```

1-й вариант задания переменной X - ошибка TypeError
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
```

2-й вариант - ошибка ValueError

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
MyX=np.asarray( train[0]);

X = MyX.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
```

Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: Добавил скриншоты

Comment: Скриншоты - это не текст. Да и нужен **полный** текст ошибки, а не три последних строчки.